# Items.Restrict Received Count not returning correct value

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm writing a sub to return messages older than 12 hours (among other things.) This is a small excerpt.

```
Dim timeMinusTwelve as String
Dim itemsOverTwelve as Integer

timeMinusTwelve = Now - .5

itemsOverTwelve = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("MyBox").Folders("Inbox").Items.Restrict("[Received] > '" & timeMinusTwelve & "'").Count

MsgBox itemsOverTwelve
```

**`" > " returns 0, " < "`** returns the total items in the folder. The real result is somewhere in the middle. Where is my syntax wrong?

Comment: look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx under the date header, you may need to modify the format of the date.  May be `Format(now()-0.5, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") `

Comment: boom shaka laka, that worked. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx) under the date header, you may need to modify the format of the date. May be `Format(now()-0.5, "ddddd h:nn AMPM")`